# Return values from method php

Tags: php, oop, return-value

I'm having trouble returning values from a class method, can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong?

This is part of a Class called Tree:

```
  public function findNode($id, $node = NULL){
    if($node == NULL) $node = $this->root;
    if($node->tid == $id){
      return $node;
    }
    else{
      foreach ($node->children as $child) {
        $this->findNode($id, $child);
      }
    }
  }
```

`

Then i call it

```
    $tree = new Tree($t);
    $a = $tree->findNode(55);
```

Debugging it I see that $node has a value just before the return, but $a is always empty (this is called outside the class scope, in normal procedural code)

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks

Edit: 
This is the content of $node just before the return, and what i was expecting to see inside $a:

```
(Object) Node
  parentNode (Object) Node
  text (String, 14 characters ) retransmission
  depth (Integer) 3
  children (Array, 0 elements)
  tid (String, 2 characters ) 55
```

Comment: Have you tried making a die or something in the if where the return is, to be sure that $node->tid will ever hit $id ?

Comment: I'm sure it does. A var_dump just before the return shows that $node is found, but when i do it with $a it's empty.

$node is also an instance of another class, called Node.

Comment: The else block doesn't return anything.

Comment: Tried that as well, adding a return outside the if/else block. Same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment it calls the function recursively it will return into the foreach block which will just resume its operations.

Try to catch the node in the foreach and check if it's null before continuing.